# PHP file upload doesn't work

Tags: php, upload

I tried to write a basic upload php script and it doesn't work. Here's the HTML:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <form action="home.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="files_to_upload">
   <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="262144000">
   <input type="submit" value="upload">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

And here's the PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['files_to_upload'])){
 if(@is_uploaded_file($_FILES['files_to_upload']['tmp_name'])) {
  echo "<br>";var_dump($_FILES);echo "<br>";
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files_to_upload']['tmpname'],'/home/user/pdf/'))
   echo '<script>alert("moved");</script>';
 }
}
?>
```

I don't get the `moved` alert , so the last function returns false I think.
Here's a `var_dump` of `$_FILES`:

```
array(1) { ["files_to_upload"]=> array(5) { 
 ["name"]=> string(15) "O0903f21011.pdf 
 ["type"]=> string(15) "application/pdf"
 ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpgaSHzm" 
 ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(314758) } 
}
```

Edit: the directory `/home/user/pdf` has all rights granted to all users.

Comment: The *destination* needs to be a file name. You are using a directory. Try something like `'/home/user/pdf/' . $_FILES['file_to_upload']['name']`

Comment: @Phil I just tried also with a filename, it's the same. I don't get the last alert.

Comment: For security reason, I would advice you to limit the File size on the server side, in your php  and not in the form. any hacker can go through your input hidden form using firefox and can change it.    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="262144000000000">
Just as an advice incase you don't about this.

Comment: @Mubo To be honest, I've never seen a browser honour a `MAX_FILE_SIZE` hidden input :)

Answer (score 4):

You have typo bug, replace:

```
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files_to_upload']['tmpname'],'/home/user/pdf/'))
   echo '<script>alert("moved");</script>';
 }
```

with

```
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files_to_upload']['tmp_name'],'/home/user/pdf/tmp_file.pdf'))
   echo '<script>alert("moved");</script>';
 }
```

Comment: I edited as you suggested, but still can't get the last alert.

Comment: if there is still problem with moving file, you should see warning inside php.log. Also try using: echo 'Moved'; instead '<script>alert("moved")</script>';

Comment: This is the log: `[Thu Feb 20 00:32:37.256211 2014] [:error] [pid 12582] [client 127.0.0.1:33025] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/php1JbDa9' to '/home/user/pdf/tmp_file.pdf'`.  I also tried to use `echo "moved"`, but got nothing.

Comment: I solved. It was the parent directory with wrong permissions.